# connect-history-api-fallback preventing API calls

Tags: javascript, express, routes, single-page-application

I am using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) in combination with the [page.js router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/page).

```
page('/', index);
page('/about', about);
page();

function index() {
    console.log("viewing index");
}

function about() {
    console.log("viewing about");
}
```

The routing works fine, but when I try to access the API, the routing prevents the call.

```
GET localhost:4000/            # index view function
GET localhost:4000/about       # about view function
GET localhost:4000/api/todos   # Nothing, instead of JSON
```

Here's the server...

```
const express = require("express");
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var todos = require("./api/routes/todos");

var app = express();

// Allow requests from all domains and localhost
app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    next();
});

const root = `${__dirname}/app/dist`

app
    .use(history())
    .use(express.static(root))
    .use(express.json())
    .use(todos)
    ;

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes it work.

```
app.use(history({
    rewrites: [
      {
        from: /^\/api\/.*$/,
        to: function(context) {
            return context.parsedUrl.path
        }
      }
    ]
 }))
```